# restsharp: task was cancelled, request aborted (issue also happened on httpclient)

Tags: httpclient, restsharp

Can someone please help in determine the cause of this?  Using restsharp I am getting taskcancelledexception: a task was cancelled.  This is a console.app using .net 4.6.1.

In class program I create two "RestClient".

```
static RestClientOptions optionsLocal = new RestClientOptions(webserverLocal)
{
    ThrowOnAnyError = true,
    Timeout = 60000
};
static RestClient myRestClientLocal = new RestClient(optionsLocal);

static RestClientOptions optionsCloud = new RestClientOptions(webserverCloud)
{
    ThrowOnAnyError = true,
    Timeout = 60000
};
static RestClient myRestClientCloud = new RestClient(optionsCloud);
```

then later in the code this function is called about every 30 seconds...

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/user/UM").AddJsonBody(tempObject);
var responseLocal = await myRestClientLocal.PostAsync<string>(request);
var responseCloud = await myRestClientCloud.PostAsync<string>(request);
```

It works for awhile (about 2 hours), then I get the task cancelled.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

thank you!!!

I was previously using httpclient but I was getting the same error so I tried switching to restsharp

Answer (score 0):

The `RestClientOptions.Timeout` is passed over directly to the wrapped instance of `HttpClient` used by RestSharp. That's why you observe the same behaviour.

`RestClientOptions` also has `MaxTimeout` property, which forces RestSharp to set up an external cancellation token source with the specified timeout. It supposes to cancel the request when the timeout expires, regardless of the `HttpClient` timeout handling.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout is measured in milliseconds, not seconds.

That's not the OP's problem but it certainly was mine!